# Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: python, windows-7

Does anyone know how to set a custom icon for a program in the taskbar?

I know that you can make a shortcut to a program to get whatever icon you want in the top left corner of the program (see image below for refrance) but how do I make a program get a new icon in the taskbar?

[image]

Comment: For some reason I cannot use a custom icon for a shortcut to python.exe -- this is probably for the same reason as your problem. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 1):

The icon displayed in the taskbar is of the executable. When you invoke a python script, it runs the Python interpreter which has that icon you want to replace. You could use something like [PyInstaller](http://pyinstaller.org) to build an executable with a custom icon or if you were using a GUI toolkit you could set the icon of the interface (for example SetIcon() in wxWidgets).

Comment: I used py2exe, then it acts like a normal program :]

Thanks anyway ;)